# go project build failed: lfstackPack redeclared in this block

Tags: go

I am new to Go, when I built my project, it returned the following the error:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go run /home/qiuwei/GoWorkSpace/src/LearnGo/SoHi/Hello.go
# runtime
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/lfstack_amd64.go:16: lfstackPack redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lfstack_64bit.go:37
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/lfstack_amd64.go:20: lfstackUnpack redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lfstack_64bit.go:41
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:13: _SS_DISABLE redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:12
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:14: _NSIG redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:13
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:15: _SI_USER redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:14
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:16: _SIG_BLOCK redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:15
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:17: _SIG_UNBLOCK redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:16
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:18: _SIG_SETMASK redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:17
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:19: _RLIMIT_AS redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:18
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:25: sigset redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os2_linux_generic.go:24
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux_generic.go:25: too many errors
```

Show my go env:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/GoWorkSpace
```

Go version: `go1.6.3`. OS: `Ubuntu 14.04`

How to fix it?

Comment: see: https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/203   remove all the extracted files and extract the Go 1.7  again. If you are still seeing the issue, you may try restarting your Terminal as well.

Comment: it worked! but I am curious about that why it worked. I dont know what happend when remove and install it again.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Remove all the extracted files and extract the 1.6 tar again. If you are still seeing the issue, you may try restarting your Terminal as well.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz
```

For more detail, [see this](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/203)

Comment: I think I know why this happened. I ran the `tar` command without sudo. And then did `ctrl-c` after seeing the file copy errors. That created some inconsistencies. I should have removed the folder again and freshly ran the tar command

Answer (score 1):

You will see this error also when using Go 1.18, as illustrated by this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/tfvb6i/go_118_redeclared_in_this_block_error/).

> I resolved my issue by removing the pre-existing 1.17 installation; try purging the /usr/local/go folder and then untar the 1.18 tarball again.
>
> My guess is that some source files had their names changed (or something along those lines), which means untaring 1.18 in-place causes these redeclaration errors.

This is illustrated by [issue 47773](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47773).

That is why the Windows installer, for install, starts by *uninstalling* Go 1.17, before installing 1.18.